# Multiple problems with annyang

Tags: speech-recognition

For my school, we have been given the task to make a 'Decision Room', much like the one in the George W. Bush Decision Room in the SMU library. For the decision room I have been creating, I have chosen to make it voice activated using annyang (kind of a cheat code it is so easy).

BUT! I have been problems getting it to understand two different words individually. When I say '2', it redirects me to the next decision, but 1 will not work.

Also, I am trying to play a little tone that I have after it registers your speech, before the redirect.

Here's my code:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
if (annyang) {
    var commands = {
        '1': function() {document.getElementById('Turn.mp3').play();
            window.location = "room1a.html";
        }
    };
    annyang.addCommands(commands);
    annyang.start();
}
}
</script>

<script>
window.onload = function(){
if (annyang) {
    var commands = {
        '2': function() {document.getElementById('Turn.mp3').play();
            window.location = "room1b.html";
        }
    };
    annyang.addCommands(commands);
    annyang.start();
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do it like this, the 2nd call of

```
annyang.addCommands(commands);
```

overwrites the first one. That's the reason it does not recognize it, when you say "one".

[See documentation here.](https://github.com/TalAter/annyang/blob/master/docs/README.md)

> initialize annyang, overwriting any previously added commands

A possible solution is, to add all your desired voice-commands in one commands-object:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
if (annyang) {
    var commands = {
        '1': function() {document.getElementById('Turn.mp3').play();
            window.location = "room1a.html";
        },
        '2': function() {document.getElementById('Turn.mp3').play();
            window.location = "room1b.html";
        }            
    };
    annyang.addCommands(commands);
    annyang.start();
}
}
</script>
```